# How do I generate excel file and send it as attachment in CakePHP2.0

Tags: excel, cakephp-2.0

Hey I am trying to create a excel file in cakephp . I have a working download link like url/fetchreport/2015-02-1 I am able to download excel from this url . Is there any way by which I can use this URL and send downloaded excel in email as a attached file .

Comment: Send it where? To the user who clicks the link?

Comment: I didn't understand  I have some user authentication in place so i need to send it as attachment I need to generate a csv file inside tmp and attach it to email

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for attaching a file in your email in cakephp.

```
$this->Email->filePaths  = array('/path/to/your/file/');
$this->Email->attachments= array('file.xls');
$this->Email->to         = 'example@example.com';
$this->Email->subject    = 'xyz';
$this->Email->replyTo    = 'client@mail';
$this->Email->from       = 'anything@mail';
$this->Email->sendAs     = 'html';
```